# JTable - Selected Row click event

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jtable, jtextfield

I have a Jtable that is populated with a linkedlist through an AbstractTableModel.

What I want to do is when I click (left-mouse click) on a row in the JTable, the linkedlist is search (in this case it contains movie titles) and displays the values in the linked list in Jtextboxes

How do I do this?

Here is the code

- GUI_g: http://pastebin.com/J3qtjn8J
- ProgramTableModel: http://pastebin.com/Dwkc9Cz3
- Processing: http://pastebin.com/qHnkvCbr
- Main: http://pastebin.com/K4yGYX9H

My guess it retrieve the data from the selected row into an array, split it, and put it into the jtextareas. How can I do this ?

Comment: i provided a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345792/java-jtable-getting-the-data-of-the-selected-row/37590500#37590500) hope it helps

Answer (score 86):

Here's how I did it:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            // do some actions here, for example
            // print first column value from selected row
            System.out.println(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        }
    });
```

This code reacts on mouse click and item selection from keyboard.

Comment: You can check if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting() && table.getSelectedRow() != -1) before System.out.println(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());

Comment: @RodrigoGarcia - can you please explain why they should add that check?

Comment: Sorry @Ascalonian, I can't remember anymore, I should have explained better.

Comment: @RodLima, what is the matter with you Rod, why can not you remember, we were coding together and you found the solution to prevent calling the event twice for each selection !

Answer (score 7):

```
 private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
     JTable source = (JTable)evt.getSource();
            int row = source.rowAtPoint( evt.getPoint() );
            int column = source.columnAtPoint( evt.getPoint() );
            String s=source.getModel().getValueAt(row, column)+"";

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);


}
```

if you want click cell or row in jtable use this way

Answer (score 6):

To learn what row was selected, add a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html), as shown in [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) in the example [`SimpleTableSelectionDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg). A [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) can be constructed directly from the linked list's `toArray()` method, and you can add a suitable listener to it for details.

Comment: If you have trouble implementing your listener, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java) with some enhancement and edit:

```
public class RowSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

        int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();

        if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting() && viewRow != -1) {

            int columnIndex = 1;

            // Better to access table row using modelRow rather than viewRow
            int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);

            // Access value at selected row at the second column (columnIndex = 1)
            Object modelvalue = table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, columnIndex);

            // Not recommended: same as above but access row using viewRow
            Object tablevalue = table.getValueAt(viewRow, columnIndex);

            // Print cell value
            System.out.println(modelvalue + "=" + tablevalue);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add `ListSelectionListener` to `JTable`:

```
 table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowSelectionListener());
```

### Important Note:

`viewRow` and `modelRow` become effectively different when applying `TableRowSorter`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) for this. It makes it very easy to map a data structure to a table model.

To react to the mouseclick on the JTable, use an ActionListener: [ActionListener on JLabel or JTable cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378096/actionlistener-on-jlabel-or-jtable-cell)

Comment: So i tried out the code, theo e of the mouselistener, how do I store in an array after I getSelectedRow() and getSelectedColumn() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MouseClicked` event:

```
private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
 // Do something.
}
```

Comment: This answers only the most obvious part of the question.