# ActionListener of JTable row

Tags: java, jtable, actionlistener

I would like to open new window when user double-click in specyfic JTable row. Type of window depends from row. How can I create ActionListener for double-click in JTable row ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378096/actionlistener-on-jlabel-or-jtable-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `getClickCount()` method, to capture double count.... getClickCount() gives info abt what type of click it was (ie single, double, triple, etc) but NOT the total click count.