# JTable: defining a nested table with clickable cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I build a JTable in which every cell is a JTable itself. I need to make the cells of the nested (inner) tables clickable so that some additional information will be displayed in a pop-up window on a mouse click.

What is the best way to do this? Should I define every cell as a button?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read something about MouseListeners (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). What have you tried yet?

Comment: I have looked through this tutorial very superficially. I am an 
absolute newbie to java.swing, so I wanted to ask experienced programmers for directions before I dive into it.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1378120/66207

Comment: I have added a MouseListener to the inner nested table and it had no effect. However when I did the same to the outer table it worked.

Comment: Is it possible that the inner table is somehow deaf to mouse events because of the nestedness? How can one overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead, create two instances of `JTable`, `master` and `detail`. In a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) added to `master`, update the model displayed by `detail` using `setModel()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513).